# Extract substring using bash

Tags: bash

I've got the string `10.11.12`. I'd like to get everything up to but not including the second dot, in other words in this case I want to return `10.11`.

I'm using bash but can't figure it out. I was hoping sed might help but I've spent ages googling and can't figure it out. e.g. this didn't work:

```
$ echo 10.11.12 | sed "s/\d*\.\d*/\0/p"
10.11.12
10.11.12
```

help!

Comment: Did you try awk?

Comment: with sed, you'd need something like `echo '10.11.12' | sed -E 's/^([^.]+\.[^.]+).*/\1/'` see [regex capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/660/capture-groups#t=201707261351266830526).... also, [sed doesn't support \d](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)... for the approach you were trying, `echo '10.11.12' | grep -oP '^\d*\.\d*'` is closest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How can I do string manipulations in bash?"). Like many common operations, this can be done with a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

```
s=10.11.12
result="${s%.*}" # Remove everything after the last .
echo "$result"
```

Of course, you could go directly to:

```
echo "${s%.*}"
```

Comment: Thx Charles. is there any way that I can embed the expression that produces `s` inside the parameter expansion? that expression is `psql -c "select version()" -q -t | awk '{print $2}' | head -1`
bash simpleton here I'm afraid

Comment: If you're already using `awk`, might as well have it do the work for you. (Actually, `awk` can *also* do the work of `head`, bringing it down to just one command... *or* we could modify the `psql` command to do the filtering itself internally, meaning you need no other command *at all*; lots of options).

Comment: yup, thx. Went with this in the end `psql -c "select version()" -q -t | awk '{print $2}' | head -1 | awk -F . '{printf $1"."$2;}'`

Comment: If **that's** real your purpose, there's probably a better answer. Example: `IFS='. ' read -r major minor point < <(psql -t -q -c 'show server_version')` -- then you have `major=9` and `minor=6` in an example of `9.6.2`. Can reconstruct `9.6` with `version=${major}.${minor}` if you really want it.

Comment: copied and pasted your suggestion there but it didn't return the correct answer and I haven't got the bash chops to figure out why. Solution I've got works so I'm happy enough.

Comment: `psql -c "select version()" -q -t | awk 'NR == 1 { version=$2; print gensub(/^([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+)[.](.*)/, "\\1", "g", version) }'` is another approach with just one `awk`

Comment: Thx. That worked perfectly. Now I have to figure out why :)

Comment: (btw, most likely reason for the above to fail if really run as an exact copy/paste, no newlines or other modifications, is if you're using `/bin/sh` rather than `bash`; `<()` is a non-POSIX extension).

Comment: So, `NR == 1` is equivalent to the `head -n 1`; the `gsub` replaces `([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+)[.].*` with just the first two match groups, so the first two strings of digits.

Comment: In our src repo there is now a link to the comment immediately above :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following without `sed`.

```
echo 10.12.13 | rev | cut -d "." -f2- | rev
```

Comment: This is rather wildly inefficient -- you're spinning up **three** processes that aren't part of bash and connecting them with FIFOs. That's a whole lot of `fork()` and `exec()` calls for something the shell could do internally.

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer and then realized the same! +1

Answer (score 0):

In `perl`:

```
echo 10.11.12 | perl -pe 's/(.*)\..*/$1/'
```

Gives what you expect